# Window functions in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions

The following Oracle SQL select allows me to select all the rows of a table that are *duplicated* according to some fields, eg, they have the same `COLUMN_1`, `COLUMN_2` and `COLUMN_3`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3 ORDER BY COLUMN_1) AS rn
        FROM    MY_TABLE t
        )
WHERE   rn > 1;
```

How to do the very same in sqlite3?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowid` and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from my_table t2
              where t2.column_1 = t.column_1 and t2.column_2 = t.column_2 and
                    t2.column_3 = t.column_3 and t2.rowid <= t.rowid
             ) as seqnum
      from my_table t
     ) t
where seqnum > 1;
```

You can use any unique key instead of `rowid`, if you have one in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The following query can get you close to what you want:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MY_TABLE t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, MIN(COLUMN_1) AS MIN_COLUMN_1
    FROM MY_TABLE
    GROUP BY COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3
) t2
    ON t1.COLUMN_2 = t2.COLUMN_2 AND
       t1.COLUMN_3 = t2.COLUMN_3 AND
       t1.COLUMN_1 = t2.MIN_COLUMN_1
WHERE
    t2.COLUMN_2 IS NULL;
```

This query works by filtering off records having the minimum `COLUMN_1` value for each `COLUMN_2`, `COLUMN_3` group.  Actually, this corresponds to the rank rather than the row number, but maybe this is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions/window functions have been in SQLite for a while. Your query will work as-is.

https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html