# SQLite equivalent of Over (Partition)

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions

I have the following query in SQL server. The database is now being utilized on a mobile device using SQLite. Can someone help with an equivalent that will work in SQLite?

```
Select DISTINCT TblSites.Customer, TblSites.Digit, Count(TblContractTasks.TaskNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY TblSites.Digit)  As TaskCount 
FROM TblContractTasks INNER Join (TblSites INNER Join TblContractDetails On TblSites.Digit = TblContractDetails.SiteDigit) On TblContractTasks.ContractNumber = TblContractDetails.ContractNumber 
WHERE TblSites.Consultant='xx'  
ORDER BY TblSites.Digit
```

Table:

```
Customer   Site   TaskNumber
------------------------
Ca          Sa      100
Ca          Sa      101
Cb          Sb      88
Ca          Sa      103
```

Results of query:

```
Customer    Site   TaskCount
-----------------------
Ca           Sa      3
Cb           Sb      1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49069627/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT s.Customer, s.Digit, COUNT(*) As TaskCount 
FROM TblSites s INNER JOIN
     TblContractDetails cd
     ON s.Digit = cd.SiteDigit INNER JOIN
     TblContractTasks t
     ON t.ContractNumber = cd.ContractNumber 
WHERE s.Consultant = 'xx'  
GROUP BY s.Customer, s.Digit
ORDER BY s.Digit;
```

This returns the result set for the data you have specified.  It seems like a more useful result set than the one you get from `SELECT DISTINCT` and your `COUNT() OVER`.